# Populate keys and values of a json object into dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vytgmLwy/)

I want to display the key and value pairs in the modelinfo object (except modelname) of getModelDetails array. I am able to console and verify the key value pairs. However, the same are not getting populated into the input fields.

```
for (var prop in getModelDetails[0].modelinfo) {
    if (prop != 'modelname') {
        $('#container').prepend(modelTemplate);

        $(".modelAttribute").each(function (index) {
            $(this).val(prop);
        });
        $(".modelType").each(function (index) {
            $(this).val(getModelDetails[0].modelinfo[prop]);
        });
    }
}
```

Please let me know a better approach to tackle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will work :

```
for (var prop in getModelDetails[0].modelinfo) {
    if (prop != 'modelname') {

        $('#container').prepend(modelTemplate);

        $(".modelAttribute").each(function (index) {
            if (index == 0) $(this).val(prop);
        });
        $(".modelType").each(function (index) {
            if (index == 0) $(this).val(getModelDetails[0].modelinfo[prop]);
        });
    }
}
```

I've created another JSFiddle here with the new code:

https://jsfiddle.net/xncwebad/